# Transition translate animation immediately after display block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a page transition by changing CSS with Javascript (jQuery). I have two pages, and one is set to display none to start.

```
page1 = $('.page1');
page2 = $('.page2');

page1.removeClass('animate').css('display', 'block').css('transform','translate3d(0,0,0)');
page2.removeClass('animate').css('display', 'none').css('transform','translate3d(0,0,0)');
```

Then I move page2 to the right without animating and display block.

```
page2.removeClass('animate')
  .css('display', 'block')  
  .css('transform','translate3d(100px,0,0)');
```

Immediately after, I animate a translation over page1.

```
page2
    .addClass('animate')
    .css('transform','translate3d(0px,0,0)');
```

The problem here is that if I do both these animations one after the other, theres no animation. But if I wait briefly between the two it works just fine.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myeopr

Comment: Can you explain the behavior you're looking to achieve?

Comment: I hope to first place page2 to the right of page1. Then animate it sliding over. In the CodePen, you'll see that if you click the move button, then the animate button, that is what I hope to see. Then reset or refresh the page. If you press the both button, the animation is run immediately after moving and displaying page2. You'll see that there is no animation when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using setTimeout with no delay

```
page2.removeClass('animate')
  .css('display', 'block')  
  .css('transform','translate3d(100px,0,0)');

setTimeout(function() {
  page2
      .addClass('animate')
      .css('transform','translate3d(0px,0,0)');
}, 0)
```

Its totally a hack but it works...